# How to generate forms dynamically based on the model objects in TurboGears?

Tags: python, turbogears2

Is there a way to generate a form based on a model object in turbogears? I came across that facility in Django - [ModelForm](http://blog.e-shell.org/130) where it generate the form based on the definition of the given model class. That is the exact feature I need in turbogears.

Answer (score 2):

TurboGears2 provides automatic form generation using [Sprox](http://sprox.org/).

You can also automatically generate full CRUD interfaces using [tgext.crud](http://www.turbogears.org/2.2/docs/main/Extensions/Crud/index.html).

For a blog post with an overview and tutorial of Automatic Forms and CRUD generation you can give a look at [this blog post](http://blog.axant.it/archives/423). It guides you at creating a photo gallery in just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a detailed article](http://blog.fruiapps.com/2012/05/TurboGears2-tutorial-to-create-a-simple-MVC-application), which explains in detail how to build stuff, you can find the associated code [here.](https://github.com/fRuiApps/cpfthw/tree/master/tgnotes)